# Does d3d9.h include windows.h? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, directx, include

When I use `#include <d3d9.h>` in my programs, I no longer need to include `windows.h` to use windows functions like `WinMain`, and `CreateWindow`.

Is this because `d3d9.h` &c. include `windows.h`?  Mainly, I'm wondering if it is possible to substitute `windows.h` with `d3d9.h`, etc, and still be able to se any functions I could use with `windows.h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you open d3d9.h you will see `# include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are right: `d3d9.h` includes `windows.h` .

But for clearness dependencies in your code I 'll keep windows.h header included. Headers sageguard will help no to include `windows.h` file twice (as it could break the compilation unit). And If some day in the future you remove `d3d9.H` inclusion, the compiler will fallback to the `windows.h` file inclusion thus your code will still compile.

Answer (score 1):

Any .h file you include is just a text file. Just open your 'd3d9.h' and see yourself whether it includes 'windows.h' or not.

However, even if it does include 'windows.h', it is still not a good idea to rely on that fact. If you need 'windows.h' - include it yourself. It won't do any harm. Header files are normally protected by so called "include guards", which make sure that thay are not included more than once.